# jquery masonry - allow for toggle (toggle goes behind div element)

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am using a simple toggle effect.

```
 //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
 $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

 //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click
 $("h4.trigger").toggle(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  }, function () {
  $(this).removeClass("active");
 });

 //Slide up and down on click
 $("h4.trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

And I am using masonry for div layout.

My issue is that the toggle container when toggled, is hidden behind other divs.

see here: http://jasondaydesign.com

thoughts?

Comment: What is the exact question, and how is it related to jQuery? If you want to avoid some elements overlapping others, you can just use `z-index`.

Comment: z-index doesn't work in this case, as the layout is controlled by masonry. I decided to forgo the toggle, due to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but used a setTimeout() to retrigger the masonry call every 50 milliseconds or so.